# How to Join to a self Joined table?

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have performed a self join:

```
SELECT 
    A.number AS number1,
    B.number AS number2 ,
    A.addres_line1,
    A.address_line2 
FROM 
    addresses A, addresses B
WHERE 
    (CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1) = CONCAT(B.addres_line1, B.addres_line1) 
    AND A.number <> B.number)
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1);
```

But I need to join another table to this so I may narrow my query down further. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: It's not the 1980's anymore; why are you using that ancient syntax? The ANSI-92 explicit join syntax has been about for *29 years*. Also, don't tag conflicting products; SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS.

Comment: In all the cases you use `CONCAT` you have the same argument repeated twice. Presumably a mistake. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Maybe he wants to be sure that the contents are the same ?  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is nothing special about a self-join as far as SQL  is concerned - you can mention the same table 99 times if you need to, in just the same way you'd join 99 different tables.

Secondly, you are using an extremely out-dated form of SQL, where tables were listed with commas. Modern SQL uses the "JOIN" keyword, which leads to much clearer queries, particularly when extended to variants such as "LEFT JOIN".

In modern SQL, with a bit of indenting for readability, and fixing some typos, your query would be:

```
SELECT
   A.number AS number1,
   B.number AS number2,
   A.address_line1,
   A.address_line2 
FROM
   addresses A
JOIN
   addresses B
   ON CONCAT(A.address_line1, A.address_line2) = CONCAT(B.address_line1, B.address_line2)
   AND A.number <> B.number
GROUP BY
   -- Note: This group by doesn't match the select list, so won't work
   CONCAT(A.address_line1, A.address_line2)
```

To join other tables, you simply add more `JOIN` clauses, each with their own `ON` clause telling the DBMS how it relates to the rest of the query:

```
SELECT
   A.number AS number1,
   B.number AS number2,
   A.address_line1,
   A.address_line2 
FROM
   addresses A
JOIN
   addresses B
   ON CONCAT(A.address_line1, A.address_line2) = CONCAT(B.address_line1, B.address_line2)
   AND A.number <> B.number
JOIN
   some_other_table C
   ON C.some_column = A.some_column
GROUP BY
   -- Note: This group by doesn't match the select list, so won't work
   CONCAT(A.address_line1, A.address_line2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is rewrite the query to (not using old-style joins):

```
SELECT A.number AS number1,
B.number AS number2 ,
A.addres_line1,
A.address_line2 
FROM addresses A
INNER JOIN addresses B ON (CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1) = 
                         CONCAT(B.addres_line1, B.addres_line1) 
                     AND A.number <> B.number)
GROUP BY CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1)
;
```

After this adding a join is done like this:

```
SELECT A.number AS number1,
B.number AS number2 ,
A.addres_line1,
A.address_line2 
FROM addresses A
INNER JOIN addresses B ON (CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1) = 
                         CONCAT(B.addres_line1, B.addres_line1) 
                     AND A.number <> B.number)
INNER JOIN otherTable C ON C.someField = A.someOtheField
GROUP BY CONCAT(A.addres_line1, A.addres_line1)
;
```

In this example I used `INNER JOIN`. Of course it is possible to use `LEFT JOIN` if that's needed for your data.